# Remotely access of Android to Android

Tags: android

Is there any API for Screen sharing and screen controlling between two android devices remotely? Thank you. Like agora is providing call and screen share between devices remotely but we can not control like TeamViewer. I want to know API with the help of that API I could control android devices remotely.

Comment: "I want to know API with the help of that API I could control android devices remotely" -- fortunately, that is not possible for ordinary apps. TeamViewer has deals with specific device manufacturers to enable this, which is why TeamViewer is not available for most devices.